# HTML Page that talk with a Python Server

Tags: python, html

I have a web server that manages the GPIO Pin of the Raspberry Pi but when I Start the server I have to click two times on the div to start the led..

What could be the problem? This is the code of the html page that I have write to manage the led

```
<script>

function onoff(led) {

var xmlhttp;
var v = document.getElementById("input_" + led).value;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)   {

        if (v == 'on'){
            document.getElementById("input_" + led).value = 'off';
            document.getElementById("par_lamp").innerHTML = "<img class='lampadina' src='http://192.168.1.91:8080/lampadina_on.png'  alt='lampadina' height='198' width='120'>";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("input_" + led).value = 'on';   
            document.getElementById("par_lamp").innerHTML = "<img class='lampadina' src='http://192.168.1.91:8080/lampadina_off.png'  alt='lampadina' height='198' width='120'>";
        }
    }

}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://192.168.1.91:8080/remote.html?led=" + led + "&action=" + v,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

```
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <img src="http://192.168.1.91:8080/logo.png" alt="logo_sito" width:"198" height:"120">
    </center>

    <p align="center" id="par_lamp">
        <img class="lampadina" src="http://192.168.1.91:8080/lampadina_off.png"  alt="lampadina" height="198" width="120">
    </p>

    <div  id="input_11" class="button" onclick="onoff(11)"  value="off">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug such things you should take a look at the development tools in your browser. All browsers let you step through your code to see exactly what happens.
In this case your flow is like this:

```
<div  id="input_11" class="button" onclick="onoff(11)"  value="off">
```

Div starts with value 'off'. If you click the code does:

var v = document.getElementById("input_" + led).value;
   xmlhttp.open("GET","http://192.168.1.91:8080/remote.html?led=" + led + "&action=" + v,true);
Which then sends the initial value of 'value' that is 'off' to your server.
Only later it toggles it to 'on' so for the next click it actually will send on.

So you either need to toggle the current status before sending the command or you need to set the initial state to 'on' so the first click sends the right command.

The code in `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {`... will only run after the `xmlhttp.send()` because it's an event handler function bound to `xmlhttp`

Comment: I try to change the state of the div to on but it doesn't work. I chamge the value tag of the div in on, is right? Every time that i start the program for the first time var v is undefined